# Usage of 'of' or 'for'

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions

> How are the falling global prices **for** natural resources impacting
>   the United States?

Should the usage here be *of* or *for*?

They both seem fine to me and I think this is grammatically correct too. If so:

What is the difference between the two in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of context, "What is the price of oil?" sounds more natural to my (American) ear than "What is the price for oil?".

There is a context where "price for oil" does sound natural to me.  If I am looking at something from the point of view of a supplier of oil, then I want to know what price I can sell the oil for.  In other words, I want to know the "price for oil".

If the author of the original quote is discussing issues from the point of view of commodity producers (such as miners and frackers), then "prices for natural resources" seems natural to me.  If the author of the original quote is discussing issues from the point of view of manufacturers or consumers, then "prices of natural resources" seems natural to me.

Answer (score 1):

While the phrase "*price **for** something*" is not ungrammatical, it occurs in English by far more seldom than "*price **of** something*" (for the same "*something*").  You can look those up in Google's [ngram viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams).  I did, with "*price of/for bread*", "*price of/for grain*", "*price of/for gold*".

The reason for that is, I believe, that the preposition "*for*" creates some distance between the concepts, as if "price" is somehow independent from the product and is said to *accompany* it or to *serve* it.

Generally, however, we perceive the price as one of the *characteristics* that **belong** to the product, not unlike *color* or *production volume*.  That is why we more likely say/write

> How are the falling global prices ***of*** natural resources impacting the United States?

Answer (score 0):

For "the amount to pay or to be paid"you should say "of"(see your example ). "For" is used meaning "a loss sustained in the accomplishment of or as the result of something ".
He is paying the price for pushing his body so hard.